How to quickly check if pcks7 binary blob is signed or encrypted, without external libraries
I can use SignedCms or EnvelopedCms classes to verify signatures and decrypt S/MIME data but I need to know in advance if it's signed or encrypted. If it's signed and I use EnvelopedCms, I get an exception. If it's encrypted and I use SignedCms - again, exception.
I don't see any way with .NET own APIs to determine if the data is signed or encrypted. So I want to peek into this data, maybe there is a flag which can be detected? I don't need/want a full-fledged pcks7 parser like BouncyCastle (it would be too heavy dependency for my library).
Because the format is binary, it's not easy to find out what exactly I should be looking for. RFC spec for pcks7 is quite complex and does not give an obvious answer. Or maybe there is a lightweight C# pcks7 parsing source code around which would let me solve this task?

As this is S/MIME, you should have access to the e-mail message headers, the MIME Content-Type header will tell be application/pkcs7-mime or application/pkcs7-signature to indicate (i.e. pinky-swear) what it is. ...or am I missing something?

AsnDecoder.ReadSequence could help you, but to be honest it's probably easier to just attempt one and catch the exception, then try the other. But yes the MIME should really tell you what it is in the first place.

@Dai Unfortunately, Outlook can marks signature as application/pkcs7-mime, with no extra parameters.

@Charlieface AsnDecoder exists since .net 4.6, I have to support .net 2.0+. Recently I found https://github.com/pornin/DDer which looks worth trying. I'm reluctant to catching exception because CryptographicException can occur for many other reasons as well and I want to let it propagate to the caller.
